# What part of the hub is referenced when speaking of hub length?

Tags: hub

In the attached image, you can see a measure of 32 and 36 mm being mentioned for the length of a bike hub. What are these measurements? I have searched and found that axle, flange or even spoke holes are given as part of the specs for hubs, but I cannot guess what these numbers are refering to, since they are either too small or too big to be referring to any of them.

[image]

Comment: Try asking the question direct to the seller?   Could be they're just box-movers and not a bicycle shop ?   Could you link to the page itself please ?

Comment: The numbers could refer to spline length of the freehub body that the cassette slips on to.  Technically the 32 and 36 are erroneous here, too since the measurement of a 7 speed freehub's splines equal 31mm, while an 8,9,10 speed freehub's splines are 35mm. See this post: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/77222/help-determining-how-many-cogs-an-unlabeled-freehub-wheel-can-take/77246#77246

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When there is choice between numbers 32 and 36 with bicycle hubs, they are spoke hole counts. This could be either a bug in the online store software or that the company has no idea what they are selling.

Comment: Thanks for your response! This is most likely the case. I took this from a retail store that sells mostly clothes and furniture, so they probably have no idea what they're selling.

Comment: The actual seller is Fahrrad.de/Brügelmann, Internetstores is their umbrella brand

Comment: Interesting. Brügelmann's own website gets this right so it could be bug somewhere. Or deliberate marketing strategy, making things a bit broken and showing an inflated "normal price" to make it feel cheap even when it's not.